# Run an onclick function of a given url automatically immediately after DOM loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I am new to js. Recently I have been trying to scrape grab m3u8 logs without loading actual browser. And the target site has a html design that we have to click an episode button to get iframe video stream.

```
Input: original video site url
Events I want: trigger onclick function to play video
Output: grab url logs like https://.../index.m3u8
```

So I have tried several ways to execute the click event on command (not web console or JavaScript in a browser), including jsdom and jsquery.

Here is the part I am interested in of the source html:

```html
<div class="y_t">
<div id="yt_l1" class="yt_l">
<ul>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRChsmgwM[c]oMbFtSxeBLAqtxoYzVaOK405Wa4JpWTw1sG[c]yw932SLCCrPHEGXJIuQWTwnbrOt9RPOvRiJNBnXAft9VIeDNPDBdkQEjjFaKjz3TUm','1')>1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReUDxvm8wM[c]5bPV1WwuFOVapxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lbzVq9RMNPMITYAwDAG[c]qA4AStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','2')>2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRP2vmUzN[c]tdP19axOJOWfNxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lb[c]Qq9RPMPYOTYhhXFDv[a]F1XStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','3')>3</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRv14zlgN[c]tQbg4Fx70bVfZxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lb[c]Zq9RPO[c]wKTYQ1VlC4qlsJStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','4')>4</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRSltWpnYKoJaV5SkLUbAaRxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lL3Vq9RONvEPTYY8DFHrqV8BStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','5')>5</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRr2420xa[c]0OMllTlLJPUKpxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lLzQq9RJMvAITdc3W1e2[a]A4AStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','6')>6</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRqgsT83NqhfaVdak7BOWPFxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lLzZq9RJNPEITYBmDAfo9F9SStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','7')>7</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReROk4mk0avwJPwxSxLFPVPZxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz4lL[c]Uq9RIMPwNTYMxDFbvrlhVStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','8')>8</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReROntmhiMKpfMl0AkL1OWKVxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz5nb3Tq9RLMvcETYM0DFfo9AhVStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','9')>9</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' onclick=ustv('ybynKRJsvW9ReRWl5W9la[c]tbaFtWx7UbBKNxoYzVaOK4xoWa4JwNAhhrQvPo9GGfKW[c]mMHNEQZAvSGz5nb3Yq9RLNfUITdM2Cwu[c][c]l9SStTJBMRGUWaDJezig3Nrpg','10')>10</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like this:

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

JSDOM.fromURL("https://ustv123.com/xxxx/", ).then(dom => {
    console.log(dom.serialize());
    const enclosingDiv = dom.window.document.getElementById('yt_l1');
    const aNodes = enclosingDiv.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log('');
    console.log(`enclosingDiv: ${enclosingDiv}`);
    console.log(`enclosingDiv.childNodes: ${enclosingDiv.childNodes}`);
    console.log(`aNodes[0]: ${aNodes[0]}`);
    console.log(`aNodes[0].outerHTML: ${aNodes[0].outerHTML}`);
    aNodes[0].onclick();
    //UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: aNodes[0].onclick is not a function
    aNodes[0]. click();
    console.log(`current href: ${dom.window.location.href}`);
    //current href: https://ustv123/xxxx/ (there should be a # at the end if click was success)
    //---------------------------output--------------------------
    //enclosing Div: [object HTMLDivElement] 
    //enclosing Div.childNodes: [object NodeList] 
    //aNodes [0]: https://ustv123.com/xxxx/#
    //aNodes[0].outerHTML: <a href="#" onclick="ustv('ybynkRJsVW9REUD2ED40M[c]wLMgtUlbQdU6JxoYzVaOK4zJic4YsRTQcsWO[a]t73uMOGesMjJKAc8wS2T6nb3SttRSMvwMIu43D1c4[c]L9JA5LODSVBBY XdY6Gmki0t64c', '1')">1</a>
});

  // I don't know how to get network resource logs with javascript, please give me some hint.
}
```

Please walk me through the way to make this work. And I don't know how to get network resource logs containing 'index.m3u8' with javascript, please give me some hint.

------------------------Updates jQuery------------------------

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
var $ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window);

JSDOM.fromURL("https://ustv123.com/xxxx/", ).then(dom => {
    console.log(dom.serialize());
    const enclosingDiv = dom.window.document.getElementById('yt_l1');
    const aNodes = enclosingDiv.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log('');
    console.log(`enclosingDiv: ${enclosingDiv}`);
    console.log(`enclosingDiv.childNodes:  ${enclosingDiv.childNodes}`);
    console.log(`aNodes[0]: ${aNodes[0]}`);
    console.log(`aNodes[0].outerHTML: ${aNodes[0].outerHTML}`);
    for(i=0; i<aNodes.length; i++){
        try{
            $(aNodes[i]).trigger('click')
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        };
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(`current href: ${dom.window.location.href}`);
    //current href: http://ustv123.com/xxxx/
});
```

Comment: Looks like the one you want is: `Btns[i].click();`   Try it with something simpler, like `<a href='#' onlick="alert('clicked')">click me</a>` - working example, click by code https://jsfiddle.net/djagcLh7/

Comment: Ok - bit simpler:  What are the `.childNodes` of a `ul` - hint: they're not `<a>`

Comment: Or, **actually look at what you're getting**:  add inside the loop: `console.log($(Btns[i]).html())` (or use other debugging methods)

Comment: I have done some debug and got the <a> but still couldn't trigger onclick event. The code in the problem is updated with output attached. Also please give me some hint as to how to get network resource logs using javascript without Web Dev Tools. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you're selecting the anchor tags, not the `<li>` elements. This will select all `<a>` descendants of the enclosing divdiv:

```
    const enclosingDiv = document.getElementById('yt_l1');
    const aNodes = enclosingDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: I have edited the code and added output in the problem, I think I got the anchor tags, but still couldn't trigger onclick event. I think there is something like a key or hash between the input url and the iframe video that should load after the click.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with jQuery like?

```
$(aNodes[0]).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Do you have jquery in your script? If so, try jQuery(aNodes[0]).trigger('click');

Comment: I declared ```var $ = require( "jquery" );``` and tried ```$(aNodes[0]).trigger('click');```. The output is ```(node:26986) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)                                (node:26986) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```

Comment: I think you should wrap it in try{}catch(err){}

Comment: Now this ```Error: jQuery requires a window with a document```

Comment: https://exceptionshub.com/error-jquery-requires-a-window-with-a-document.html Take a look about this approach to handle the window

Comment: I handled it, sorry for bothering you with minor bug. But the click still didn't happened. Updates in problem above.

Comment: Try a different approach, extract the function of the onclick and execute it with eval